# TextViews displayed separately in Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I have a fragment in my app which gets data from parse.com and displays it in a ListView.

I am retrieving two string values from Parse. My problem is that the two string values are being displayed in separate rows in the ListView (see image below)

http://postimg.org/image/vsaw8lsbh/33225549/

My aim is to have the time in the same row as the subject.

listview_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

listview_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:padding="5sp"
android:textSize="15sp" />
```

fragmentClass

```
public class TuesdayFragment extends Fragment { 



// Declare Variables
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflat and return the layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_main, container, false);
    Parse.initialize(getActivity(), "***parsekey***", "***parsekey***");


    new RemoteDataTask().execute();


    return v;
}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading Programme, Please Wait :)");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();

    }



    @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>  ("Program");
                query.orderByAscending("pSession");
                ob = query.find();

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        return null;
    }

protected void onPostExecute(Void result){



    listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);        
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item);
    for (ParseObject country : ob) {
       adapter.add((String) country.get("pSubject"));
       adapter.add((String) country.get("pTime"));
    }       
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);       
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();  
    }

 }
 }
```

Comment: you need something a little more complex than an ArrayAdapter<String>. A SimpleAdapter could be a simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
adapter.add((String) country.get("pSubject"));
adapter.add((String) country.get("pTime"));
```

to

```
adapter.add((String) country.get("pSubject") + "\n" + (String) country.get("pTime"));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :D probably pushing it a bit here but can i control the position of them programatically?

Comment: '\n' is a control character for new line.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your adapter only accepts one textview (listview item only has one textview).

Every time you do adapter.add you are going to add a new line to your list.

Change your listview_item so that it has 2 values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then you have to add a custom adapter and fill in the textviews inb the overrided method `getView`, like this:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);

        }

        final Country p = items.get(position);

        if (p != null) {

            TextView tt = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.text);// nome

            TextView date = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_date);

            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText(country.get("pSubject"));
            }
            if (date != null) {

                data.setText(country.get("pTime"));
            }
        return v;

    }
```

Here is a tutorial that can help you: [Custom listview Item row](http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-items-row/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Getting an error in the list view_item saying "Wrong orientation? No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal, yet this layout has multiple children where at least one has layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: i edited my answer so that it has a layout of a listview item cell that I use without problems. This layout has the text side by side. If you want it to be in the next line change the layout orientation to vertical: ` android:orientation="vertical"`